# Any OpenJDK equivalent to JRockit's Weaving/AOP API?

Tags: aop, java, jrockit, load-time-weaving

I'm rather impressed by what I see of [JRockit's built-in weaving/AOP support](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jvm-aop-2-098025.html).  Is there any similarly-easy-to-use support for AOP weaving on OpenJDK?

The code I am trying to instrument is often loaded via Maven, so hooking in to classloaders to e.g. install a weaving classloader may be difficult.  A JMTI-based solution may or may not be practical.